# Can I visit Paris with a visa for Germany which I got in India?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, germany, france, long-stay-visas

I have got a Deutchesland visa for Germany in India. I want to go Paris too. Do I need different Visa for that?it's written
Valid for.  Deutchesland
Type D

Comment: Please clarify your question: Are you asking if you can travel to France using a visa for Germany obtained in India?

Comment: Yes I wanna go to Paris with Deutchesland visa...

Comment: Can you visit Paris during your trip to Germany?  Yes, but you need to be careful of a couple of things.  Can you use your German visa for a trip to Paris?  Maybe, and if so, you'll need to be even more careful of the same things.  If the linked duplicate doesn't make it clear, please let us know what parts you do not understand.

Comment: I am bit confused with Schengen visa and Deutchesland Visa

Comment: What TYPE OF VISA do you have? What is shown in the VALID FOR line at the top?

Comment: @Sneha P Nair Does your visa look like https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/read_visa_sticker_en

Comment: No in the place of Schengen....mine is written "Deutchesland"

Comment: With the new information that it is a type D visa, I think this question is now possible to answer -- or, more likely, mark as a duplicate. There are plenty of duplicates, e.g., https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/can-i-visit-other-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-schengen-visa-or-residency-p -- but ideally we should find one with an answer that addresses the confusing way the "Valid for" field works for D visas.

Comment: Here is one that answers the "valid for" confusion: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74786/can-i-travel-across-eu-with-my-student-visa/74788#74788

Answer (score 2):

There is no border control between Schengen states. But, since the visa is provided by Germany, it means that the main destination shall be Germany, not France.

If your itenary changes so much that your main destination is not Germany, then its better to apply for new visa, as if they find out, then you will be sent back and you will have much difficulty in obtaining visa to EU in future.

> Edit: Since your visa is type D (I am assuming a long term visa.),
>   then there is no restriction for you to visit France.