# Can I enter Spain with a few days left in expiration of my French student visa?

Tags: germany, france, spain, visa-expiration, student-visas

I am an Erasmus Mundus student with semesters in France, Spain and Germany. I am in possession of a French Type-D student visa (sauf-CTOM) with multientry, which expires on 20 Aug 2022. I have already applied for a German visa at the German embassy in Madrid and it is expected to be ready by 19 Aug 2022. Had the following queries:

1. Can I enter Spain directly with the French visa to collect my German visa from Madrid?
2. As my French visa expires on 20 Aug 2022, would I be allowed entry into Spain around 17 Aug 2022 with sufficient proof (eg: visa collection appointment at the German embassy)?

Your help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I travel across EU with my student visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74786/can-i-travel-across-eu-with-my-student-visa) The accepted answer says "A type D visa, like a residence permit, allows you to make short trips to the other Schengen countries". There are no formal border checks at the France/Spain border, and if you have your valid visa and ID with you, you should be good to go.

Comment: Are you going to Spain directly from France (or any other Schengen country) or are you entering from a non-Schengen country?

Answer (score 1):

This visa does allow you to travel to other Schengen countries and is still valid. In the somewhat unlikely event that you are checked at the border (not seen any enforcement on a trip last week), there could be some questions about your intent to leave Spain and the Schengen area in time but you have got that covered convincingly with your German studies and visa appointment.